# Can't use React hooks in react-router-dom components

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

why i can't use react hooks in route direct components ,elsewhere i can use hooks no problem occured .
Anyone can answer this problem please and how can i use hooks in these component

here's the error

./src/Pages/bookingPage.js
Line 6:29:  React Hook "useState" is called in function "bookingPage" which is neither a React function component or a custom React Hook function  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

here's my app.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import AuthPage from './Pages/authPage'
import EventPage from './Pages/eventPage'
import BookingPage from './Pages/bookingPage';
import MainNavigator from './component/MainNavigator';
import AuthContext from './component/context/auth-context';

function App() {
  const [token, setToken] = useState(null);
  const [userId, setUserId] = useState(null);
  const login = (token, userId, expirationTime) => {
    setToken(token);
    setUserId(userId);
  }
  const logout = () => {
    setToken(null);
    setUserId(null);
  }
  return (
    <Router>
      <React.Fragment>
      <AuthContext.Provider value={{ token: token, userId: userId, login: login, logout: logout }}>
        <MainNavigator />
        <Switch>
          {!token && <Redirect from="/" to="/auth" exact />}
          {token && <Redirect from="/" to="/events" exact />}
          {token && <Redirect from="/auth" to="/events" exact />}
          {!token && <Route path="/auth" component={AuthPage} />}
          <Route path="/events" component={EventPage} />
          {token && <Route path="/bookings" component={BookingPage} />}
        </Switch>
      </AuthContext.Provider>
      </React.Fragment>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

here's my booking page component

```
 import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { Grid, } from '@material-ui/core';

import '../App.css';
const bookingPage = () => {
    const [book, setBook] = useState(false);
    return (
        <Grid container className='container_booking'>
            <Grid item lg={12} sm={12} xs={12}>
                <h1>bookibPage</h1>
                {book}
                <button onClick={() => setBook(true)}>click me</button>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    )
}

export default bookingPage
```

Comment: `bookingPage` isn't a valid react component name, they ***must*** be PascalCased. It's a naming convention thing.

Comment: thanks @DrewReese .How can i forget that basic thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call Hooks from React function components.

Read this [Rules of React-Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html)

Change name of function to `BookingPage`

```
const BookingPage = () => {
    const [book, setBook] = useState(false);
    return (
        <Grid container className='container_booking'>
            <Grid item lg={12} sm={12} xs={12}>
                <h1>bookibPage</h1>
                {book}
                <button onClick={() => setBook(true)}>click me</button>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    )
}

export default BookingPage
```

Comment: @VishalSingh Please upvote and accept my answer if it solves your problem. That would help me to keep myself motivated

Answer (score 0):

You bookingPage component name should start with a capital character

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { Grid, } from '@material-ui/core';

import '../App.css';
const BookingPage = () => {
    const [book, setBook] = useState(false);
    return (
        <Grid container className='container_booking'>
            <Grid item lg={12} sm={12} xs={12}>
                <h1>bookibPage</h1>
                {book}
                <button onClick={() => setBook(true)}>click me</button>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    )
}

export default BookingPage
```